# IQKeyboardManager doesn’t work when using safeAreaLayoutGuide

Tags: ios, swift, iqkeyboardmanager

I've got a button whose top anchor is: `backButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true`
And I've got a text view whose top anchor is: `storyDescription.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: numOfChapters.bottomAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true` (I've got elements between these but they don't affect this unusual behaviour).

When I tap on the textView it sometimes goes above the view, this only happens when I use `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide`, But when I don't use `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide`, it doesn't happen. And again, This only happens when I use `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide` and all the elements below are connected to the element that uses safeAreaLayoutGuide.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]